Unable to start postgresql after server restart
Post Ubuntu server restart i am unable to start the postgresql in the server, i am getting the below error
2024-08-09 15:17:19.217 IST [24899]: [1-1] db=,user=,app=,client= FATAL:  58P01: could not open log file "/var/log/postgres/postgresql-2024-08-09_151719.log": No such file or directory
2024-08-09 15:17:19.217 IST [24899]: [2-1] db=,user=,app=,client= LOCATION:  logfile_open, syslogger.c:1293
2024-08-09 15:17:19.219 IST [24899]: [3-1] db=,user=,app=,client= LOG:  00000: database system is shut down
2024-08-09 15:17:19.219 IST [24899]: [4-1] db=,user=,app=,client= LOCATION:  UnlinkLockFiles, miscinit.c:1148
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output
pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
16  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/16/main /var/log/postgres/postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log
I need to change log file to /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-16-main.log but it was writing to another file in postgresql.conf log_collector was in off but some how the logs are writing to postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log this file. Need to change this location
Please help
